# PHP mysql im looking for good format and eliminate messy codes

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php codes which have a lot of `mysql_query` and `or die ( mysql_error() )`

how can i lessen the mysql_query or is the or die ( mysql_error() ) really need for my codes?

Im going to paste my codes here.

```
$sqlScore = "UPDATE game SET currentTurn = '1', remainingTiles='".$remainingTiles."' WHERE gameID = '".$gameID."'";
mysql_query( $sqlScore ) or die ( mysql_error() );

$ScoreSelect = set_mysql( "SELECT * FROM game WHERE gameID = '".$gameID."'" );
$up_gameID = $ScoreSelect['gameID'];
$set_p1 = $ScoreSelect['player1'];

// CHECK IF GAMEID EXIST FOR SCORE
$checkData = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM score WHERE gameID = '".$gameID."' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
$rcd = mysql_fetch_array( $checkData );
$rcd['gameID'] == $gameID 
? mysql_query( "UPDATE score SET score = '".$score."' WHERE gameID = '".$gameID."' " ) or die ( mysql_error() ) 
: mysql_query( "INSERT INTO score VALUE( '', '".$gameID."', '".$player1."', '".$score."')" ) or die ( mysql_error() );

// INSERT SQL WORD DATA
$sqlWD = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO word_data VALUE( '', '".$gameID."', '', '".$worddata."')" ) or die ( mysql_error() );

// CHECK FOR TILE
$sqlCheckRow = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM wctilerack WHERE gameID = '".$up_gameID."' AND email = '".$up_email_player1."' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
if ( mysql_num_rows( $sqlCheckRow ) == "1" ) {
    // INSERT wctilerack
    $sqlTileUP = mysql_query( "UPDATE wctilerack SET tiles = '$playerRack' WHERE gameID = '".$up_gameID."' AND email = '".$up_email_player1."' ") or die ( mysql_error() );
} else {
    // INSERT wctilerack
    $sqlTileINSERT = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO wctilerack VALUE('', '".$up_gameID."', '".$up_email_player1."', '$playerRack' ) ") or die ( mysql_error() );
}

// UPDATE lastPlayed
$sqlUpdatePlayed = mysql_query( "UPDATE user SET lastPlayed=NOW() WHERE email = '$up_email_player1' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
// UPDATE word
$sqlUpdateWord = mysql_query( "UPDATE game SET lastWord = '".$xword[2]."', lastPoints='".$score."' WHERE gameID = '$up_gameID' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
//$sqlInsertWord = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO word_data VALUE( '', '".$up_gameID."', '', '".$xword[2]."' )" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
/*$sqlCheckSK = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM gameTileSkins WHERE gameID = '$gameID' AND email = '$up_email_player1' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
if ( mysql_num_rows( $sqlCheckSK ) == '1' ) {
    $skUP = mysql_query( "UPDATE gameTileSkins SET tileSkin='$tileSkinID' WHERE gameID = '$gameID' AND email = '$up_email_player1' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
} else {
    // INSERT gameTileSkins
    $sqlSK = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO gameTileSkins VALUE('', '$gameID', '$up_email_player1', '$tileSkinID')" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
}*/
```

if you noticed lots of query called.
its a game application that fetch all the records and update.
is there a way that we can clean the codes.

Comment: this is as abstract as it can get, so I'm posting it as a comment - I would use **[LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)** to join your SELECT statements, since gameID seems to be a common field in all queries... also, if you're concerned about repeating same code, create a function that performs mysql_query and die() functions together - like `function do_sql($sql) {mysql_query($sql) OR die('ERROR!');}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is working and years of bug fixes you should not change it as little as possible. 
I recommend you grep through you code and find 'mysql_query' calls. And replace it with a similar function first.

```
mysql_query( some text here ) or die(mysql_error());
```

should be replaced with

```
handle_query( some text here )
```

and `handle_query` function should be defined as

```
function handle_query($query){
    mysql_query( $query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

After that run your tests. If all goes well.  Change `handle_query` function body.

> how can i lessen the mysql_query or is the or die ( mysql_error() ) really need for my codes?

You can use sed/grep. Assuming your code is in `junk_code.php` you can use this command to get read of those `or die (mysql_error())`;

```
sed 's/mysql_query/handle_query/g'  junk_code | sed 's/\s*or\s*die\s*(\s*mysql_error(\s*)\s*)\s*//g'
```

But dont forget to take backup before playing with such legacy code. These codes has long years experiences in it. May be lots of bug fixes. You surely dont want to break it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: Switch over to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). The mysql functions are no longer recommended. From the PHP manual:

> Use of this extension (mysql) is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or
>   PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

In terms of actually cleaning up your code, you should look into the concept of [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). A wrapper class for common operations (connecting, querying etc) will help you clean things up a little. Creating your own wrapper class is a great way to learn and it'll help you abstract the majority of your common database queries.

Comment: I think OP wanted to know how to lessen those junk

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Abstracting those queries and sticking to the "Don't Repeat Yourself" concept would help with all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to start sacrificing your error handling or reduce the number of queries you are using, no, you can't. Look at just cleaning your code base up with more newlines, or move to a MVC style to effectively abstract each of your database queries into its own function.

Answer (score 0):

```
// CHECK IF GAMEID EXIST FOR SCORE
$checkData = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM score WHERE gameID = '".$gameID."' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
$rcd = mysql_fetch_array( $checkData );
$rcd['gameID'] == $gameID 
? mysql_query( "UPDATE score SET score = '".$score."' WHERE gameID = '".$gameID."' " ) or die ( mysql_error() ) 
: mysql_query( "INSERT INTO score VALUE( '', '".$gameID."', '".$player1."', '".$score."')" ) or die ( mysql_error() );
```

and

```
$sqlCheckRow = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM wctilerack WHERE gameID = '".$up_gameID."' AND    email = '".$up_email_player1."' " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
if ( mysql_num_rows( $sqlCheckRow ) == "1" ) {
// INSERT wctilerack
$sqlTileUP = mysql_query( "UPDATE wctilerack SET tiles = '$playerRack' WHERE gameID = '".$up_gameID."' AND email = '".$up_email_player1."' ") or die ( mysql_error() );
} else {
// INSERT wctilerack
$sqlTileINSERT = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO wctilerack VALUE('', '".$up_gameID."', '".$up_email_player1."', '$playerRack' ) ") or die ( mysql_error() );
}
```

Instead of these codes you can write a single query for(insert/update) using ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax.

```
eg:     mysql_query("INSERT INTO score VALUES ('', '".$gameID."', '".$player1."', '".$score."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = '".$score."'") or die ( mysql_error() );
```